# How does object file linking of extern symbols work?

Tags: assembly, linker, x86, x86-64

Let's say you have a C file like this:

```
extern void foo(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This generates the following x86-64 assembly:

```
extern _foo
global _main:
    callq foo
    retq
```

When the compiler writes the object file for this, how does it tell the linker to come back and fill in the actual address for 'foo'?  Does it leave a special code in the address field of the callq instruction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured this out (maybe someone to comment to let me know if this is right).

The compiler emits "relocation entries" in the object file.  This is a table listing the offsets in the object file that point to addresses that need to be updated.  In the example above, there would be one relocation entry for "callq foo" that would point to the first byte of the address field in callq.

During linking, the linker iterates over all the relocation entries and fills in the correct address(es).

I looked [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) and [here](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker01.html) to figure this out.

Comment: Yeah. You can look at the relocation entries using `objdump -dr` or `readelf` for example.